# Efficient comparison of all elements of python dict

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

I am looking for a more efficient way to do comparisons between all elements of a python dict.

Here is psuedocode of what I am doing:

```
for key1 in dict:
    for key2 in dict:
        if not key1 == key2:
            compare(key1,key2)
```

if the length of the dict is N, this is N^2 - N.  Is there any way of not repeating the elements in the second loop?  For lists, this would be:

```
N = len(list)
for i in range(1:(N-1)):
    for j in range((i+1):N):
        compare(list[i], list[j])
```

anyway to do this for the dict case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
>>> import itertools
>>> 
>>> d = {1:2, 2:3, 3:4}
>>> 
>>> for k0, k1 in itertools.combinations(d,2):
...     print 'compare', k0, k1
... 
compare 1 2
compare 1 3
compare 2 3
```

if you don't care about whether you get (1,2) or (2,1).  [Of course you could iterate over `sorted(d)` or some variant if you wanted a particular order, or compare both (k0, k1) and (k1, k0) if that mattered.]

[BTW: don't call your lists list or your dicts dict-- that clobbers the builtins, and they're handy to have around.]

Answer (score 3):

You could use an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and then write code similar to what you've already got for lists.

Here's an example:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def compare(a, b):
    print "compare", a, b

d = OrderedDict([('banana', 3), ('apple', 4), ('pear', 1), ('orange', 2)])

for key1 in d:
    for key2 in reversed(d):
        if key1 == key2:
            break
        compare(key1, key2)
```

When I run this it prints:

```
compare banana orange
compare banana pear
compare banana apple
compare apple orange
compare apple pear
compare pear orange
```

Comment: @srgerg: nice indeed, but you don't actually need OrderedDict, simply  `for key1 in sorted(d)`

Comment: @thg435 I could be wrong, but I don't think that will work. Firstly, the `reversed` function won't work on an ordinary dict, but will work on an OrderedDict. Also the `reversed` function yields the members of an iterable in reverse order, not descending order. For example, `reversed([3,1,2,5,4])` yields 4,5,2,1,3; not 5,4,3,2,1. Lastly, sorting adds an O(n log n) operation on top of the existing code, when the OP was asking for a more efficient solution than their existing solution.

Comment: @srgerg: just replace `d=OrderedDict(...` with `d=sorted(original_dict)`

Comment: @thg435 Ok, but note that `d=sorted(original_dict)` means that `d` will be a list, not a dict. While that will work in the code sample I've provided, its not clear to me that it will work in the OPs application, and its not clear that it would be more efficient than the OPs original solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> equal = lambda d1, d2: all(d1.get(k) == d2.get(k) for k in set(d1.keys() + d2.keys()))
>>> print equal({'a':1, 'b':2}, {'b':2, 'a':1})
True
>>> print equal({'a':1, 'b':2}, {'b':2, 'a':2})
False
```

This solution is quite effective: `all` is lasy - stops at the first `False`, and generator expression is lasy too :)

```
def deep_equal(d1, d2):
    ''' Deep comparison '''
    if type(d1) != type(d2):
       return False
    if isinstance(d1, dict):
       return all(ddeep_equal(d1.get(k), d2.get(k))
           for k in set(d1.keys() + d2.keys()))
    return d1 == d2
```